# JavaScript: Run a function when a new variable is created

Tags: javascript, function, reset

I was wondering if it was possible to store the value, and add a function to the object when I create a variable:

```
String.prototype.reset = function(){
    return initialValue;
}
var str = "foo";
str = 10;
str.reset(); //str === "foo"
```

I do not want to store data in another variable, as it takes another line of code and another variable name.

Comment: The rules for variable creation and value assignment are defined in the language specification. It doesn't provide any access to the mechanism by which it occurs, which is implementation dependent. However, a host environment might provide events you can listen for, but I don't know of any.

Comment: `str` isn’t even a String any more when you call `reset` in your example so it will throw an error. I don’t see in any case how you avoid another variable even if it’s hidden in the class, because you have to track the initial value somewhere.

Comment: Even in the *reset* method, the initial value is returned, it's not assigned to the variable. You'd need something like `this.value = this.initialValue` and on Object.prototype so it "works" on all object types.